# ASRock Z87 Extreme 3 Motherboard

Tags: sound, webcam

I have assembled my own PC following the instructions in Linux Format Magazine 185. The motherboard is ASRock z87 Extreme 3. Everything works great...it was much easier than I expected. However, the onboard audio does not work (the USB headphones do!) and the camera does not show a picture. Both are detected...but neither works. The camera (Logitech) did work with my Dell Lap top running Ubuntu 14.04. The new rig is also running 14.04 (no dual boot). I know the drivers are supplied by the kernel...but, why would it work on one machine and not the other?